# Does a covering of $SU(n)$ by subsets imply $SU(n)$ is decomposable into those subsets?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\left\{ G_i \right\}_{i = 1}^{m}$ be a set of subsets of $SU\left( n\right),\,n \geq 2$ such that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} G_i = SU\left( n\right)$$
I strongly suspect this implies $$\prod_{i=1}^{m} G_i \triangleq \left\{g_1 g_2 \cdots g_m;\; g_1 \in G_1, g_2\in G_2,\ldots,g_m \in G_m\right\} = SU\left( n\right)$$ but am unsure about how to prove this (or procure a counterexample). Any assistance would be appreciated.

**Note:** I'm specifically interested in finding out whether the implication holds for *every* set of subsets with the given property.

Comment: sure; let all of the $g_i$ be the identity except for one.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive: I'm looking for whether the implication holds for *every* set of subgroups with the given property. I'll clarify this in the working.

Comment: I don't understand the note, the question was general to begin with?

Comment: @muzzlator: No, you're right. The problem is that these "subgroups" aren't guaranteed to contain an identity. They obey the other group axioms, though. What is that called? A semi-group?

Comment: @muzzlator: I've fixed the OP by changing "subgroups" to "subsets". After carefully considering the problem I'm looking at, the only thing I can say about them is that their elements associate. None of the other group axioms hold, including closure.

Comment: That last makes no sense. What do you mean by their elements associating? If you mean the multiplication of them is associative then that says nothing, as these are subsets of a group. Anyway, for arbitrary subsets, this will not hold, as can be seen by picking the subsets as a subgroup and its complement (in which case the product will not contain any elements from that subgroup).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: OK. That answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each $G_i$ contains $I$. If the union covers $SU(n)$, then any $X \in SU(n)$ is in  $G_i$ for some $i$. Then $X$ is also in the product by using $I$ for each $G_j$ with $i \neq j$ and $X$ from $G_i$